# How add password to the running command in ansible

Tags: shell, ansible, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a task to run password-encryption cypher tool.

```
  tags: encrypting
  command: sh {{ansible_env.HOME}}/wso2/apim/{{item}}/wso2am-2.6.0/bin/ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure 
  with_sequence: start=1  end={{ no_of_nodes }}
```

This task requires a password. But it fails because the prompt password is not provided to send the password. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use [expect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html#expect-executes-a-command-and-responds-to-prompts) module. Quoting the [example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html#examples) how-to provide the `command` with a password

```
- name: Case insensitive password string match
  expect:
    command: passwd username
    responses:
      (?i)password: "MySekretPa$$word"
  # you don't want to show passwords in your logs
  no_log: true
```

In your case, the task may look similar to this one. Fit the `password` prompt to your needs

```
- expect:
    command: sh {{ansible_env.HOME}}/wso2/apim/{{item}}/wso2am-2.6.0/bin/ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure 
    responses:
      (?i)password: "MySekretPassword"
  loop: "{{ range(1, no_of_nodes)|list }}"
  no_log: true
  tags: encrypting
```